# Keep a list of ids in Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Storing Redux objects in the store by key/id makes them better for lookup, more easily modified, deleted, etc. It's also more efficient.

```
entities: {
  3f9KwR2: {
    first: 'John'
    last: 'Johnson'
  },
  zyR4oLl: {
    first: 'Tina'
    ...
```

I have noticed many people also storing a list of `ids` in their reducer as well ([example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/reducers/paginate.js)). In the case above, it would just be an array `['3f9KwR2', 'zyR4oLl']`.

This [Redux recipe](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) suggests keeping a list of ids solely to keep the original order of your data (how it is ordered in an API response, for example). If keeping the original order is not important, does storing a list of ids server any purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not serve any purpose. The list of ids can be retrieved in your example with `Object.keys(state.entities)`, except you know nothing about the order. If you do not care about the order, there is no difference between doing this and maintaining a separate list of ids.